# Size of collection in memory vs size of collection on disk

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management, collections

I have a collection where each item consists of the following:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> m_Dict1;    
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> m_Dict2; 
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> m_Dict3;  
string m_filePath;
string m_extension;
string m_directoryFullPath;
string m_fileName;
string m_directory;
```

When I save the collection to a binary file, the file size is approximately 62meg.

When I start the program that does very little, except for restore the collection from the binary file, my application process in task manager shows that my application is using about 312meg.

Would this be an indication that I have something unexpected going on?

Should the size of the saved binary file resemble the size of the same data held in the collection in memory? Or is it wrong to expect that the sizes of the two should be similar?

Comment: Concurrent collections have memory overhead.

Comment: ...and it only becomes worse on bigger data sets.

Comment: What would you estimate to be an average length of the majority of your strings? How many items on average do `m_DictN`s have?

Comment: The strings are mostly file names and directory paths, with some information about the file, such as if it is an image and if it has tags stored in it.  I would estimate the count in the collection to be around 50,000 at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code that loads the binary file to the collections onto a new function.
From the app main() call this new function.
After that, and always from main(), call GC.Collect() and check again

Comment: Thank you for the tip; i'm obviously still new at this stuff, and so I hadn't come across GC.Collect() before.  Reading up on it, I can see how it is a useful tool.  I will give this a try.  Thank you again for taking the time to offer some helpful advice.

Comment: Glad to help. Check out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FRG5Gg1Sc for a little intro about code / memory profiling, it's only 2 minutes and should give you a good head start.